# How can i get only ssn from the full sentence?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to get only ssn from this full sentence

```
please don't share this: 234-60-1422
```

I need only this

```
234-60-1422
```

This is my function # Return the Social Security number from a string.

```
def grab_ssn(string)
    ssn = /(\d{3})[^\d]?(\d{2})[^\d]?(\d{4})/
    returnString = ""
    if ssn =~ string
        print returnString = string.scan(ssn)
    else
        puts "not match"
    end
end
```

But I got array like this

```
[["234", "60", "1422"]]
```

Are there any way that I can get that text format not an array?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want `[^\d]?` and not, say, `-?`? The former will match any non-digit character so e.g. `234O60l1422` will match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the capturing groups. `scan` method in ruby gives first preference to capturing groups than matches. So it prints only the value of capturing group in an array.

```
ssn = /\d{3}[^\d]?\d{2}[^\d]?\d{4}/
```

Add word boundary if necessary..

```
ssn = /\b\d{3}[^\d]?\d{2}[^\d]?\d{4}\b/
```